# How to Perform add collection with inner collection firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("blog").add({
                name: topic
            }).collection("messages").add({
                name: user,
                title: title,
                ideas: ideas,
                timestamp:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a document to both the parent and child collection, you have to add it to the parent first, because you need it's document id to create a path to the child collection, so in your code you would have to do something like this:

```
db.collection("blog").add({
    name: topic
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    db.collection("blog")
      .doc(docRef.id)
      .collection("messages")
      .add({
          name: user,
          title: title,
          ideas: ideas,
          timestamp:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
       })
})
```

Comment: @MaharshGheewala If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
Following these simple rules you increase your own reputation score and at the same time you keep us motivated to answer your questions.